# High density implies divergence? Or not?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $S$ be an infinite subset of the positive integers, and $P_n=s\cap\{1,2,...,n\}$. Let $(\log n / n) |P_n|\to 440$. a) Is it true that $\sum_{k\in S}1/k$ diverges? Note that if P=prime numbers, then 1 works instead of 440, and the sum is divergent. I just want to generalize this. b) Can we go beyond, and put something much bigger then $\log n/n$ and claim the same divergence?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not very much bigger than $\log n/n$.  If I'm not mistaken, it's not true if you replace $\log(n)/n$ by  $\log^\alpha(n)/n$ for $\alpha > 1$.
For example, take a random $S$ where each integer $k > 1$ is (independently) included with probability $1/\log(k)^\alpha$.  Then I **think**
$\frac{\log(n)^\alpha}{n} |P_n|$ should go to a positive constant as $n \to \infty$, while $\mathbb E \sum_{k \in S} 1/k = \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k \log(k)^\alpha} < \infty$, so almost surely $\sum_{k \in S} 1/k$ converges.